# Deny access specific file extenions in specific dir on NGNIX

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to deny access on `manifest.json`, `list.json` (or simply `*.json`) and all sourcemaps `*.maps` in `packs/` folder.

I tried something like:

```
location ^/packs/.*\.(json|map)$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```

Didn't worked out. I still access those files :(

How can I restrict access to those files in `packs/` folder?

Comment: Didn't you miss a `~` sign? `location ~ ^/packs/.*\.(json|map)$ { ... }`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Nope. Didn't worked either :(

Comment: @Mandy8055 This deny all subfolders. I want to deny on `packs/` folder only.

Comment: I think Ivan's comment is correct. I got cached version probably. After clearing browser I got 404.

Comment: @IvanShatsky can you please post that as an answer indicated that what I forgot there, so I can select as an answer?

Comment: Read the comment under my answer, if you want to return HTTP 404 Not found, leave only `return 404;` and if you want to return HTTP 403 Forbidden, leave only `deny all;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use regex matching location, those locations declared with a `~` (or `~*` if you want case-insensitive matching) sign:

```
location ~ ^/packs/.*\.(json|map)$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: The `deny all;` is probably extraneous and not needed if you want to return 404. If both directives are kept, then only denial will be applied, which will result in 403.